# why second time cp command is faster

Tags: linux, shell, caching, benchmarking

When I execute `cp folder1 folder2 -rf`,for the first time it takes around 10 mins. But when it I execute the second command `cp folder1 folder3 -rf`, it takes around 1 min. `folder1` contains about 100 000 files.

Why is there run time improvement for the second time?

Comment: Just guessing: Maybe because the content of `folder1` is in memory so that it can be copied faster?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is because of page caching. Run `sync ; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` to make it slow again.

Further reading:

- http://jim.studt.net/depository/index.php/flushing-caches-for-benchmarking-in-linux
- https://superuser.com/a/319287/236874

Comment: Small nitpick: The invocation of `sync` here is rather useless. The reason why one would want to sync is that dirty objects cannot be purged. However, `sync` only _initiates_ writeback, it does not really "sync" (that is, block until completion of writeback). So dropping caches immediately after calling sync is pretty much the same as not syncing.

Answer (score 6):

The first time the files are read from your hard drive.

The second time the files are read from memory.

Linux, as most operating systems, caches accessed files/blocks in memory.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the file now is stored in the memory cache. The first time this command was executed, it had to read the file from disk, which is much slower. This is also important to remember if you want to run any form of benchmark that use disk access, for example by adding a "cat MYFILE >/dev/null" before the actual benchmark is executed to get consistent results.